# How do I make the height responsive?

Tags: css

How do I make the height of text(tagline) responsive?
I tried `padding bottom`, but it doesn't work. Is there a way I can make the text's height responsive?

```
<p class="logo">LoremIpsum</p>
<p class="tagline">LoremIpsum</p>
<img class="mainImage" src="FullSizeRender.jpg">
```

css:

```
body{
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0;
}


.logo{
 font-size: 3em;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
}


.tagline{
 font-size: 0.9em;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 position: absolute;
 top:20%;
 /* padding-bottom: 20%;*/
}

.mainImage{
 width: 50%;
 height: auto;
}
```

Comment: If you're wanting to change the size of the font, you could consider using viewport units: https://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Comment: have you tried using `line-height`?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the `<p>` inside a `<div>` or `<span>` and assigning the height values to them.

Comment: height is not really an issue, as people are used to scroll vertically. The big problem is width.